# How to import specific data from a Notepad to Excel Worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

First i will show how exactly my notepad looks.Please see the attached image. Then i will explain what i am looking for.

[image]

From this i want to import the  "Cutter PA Value', Cutter BR Value & Cutter Radius Value into separate column's of excel worksheet. My Excel sheet will have column names as Cutter PA, Cutter Radius, Cutter BR. i want notepad values to be feed inside each corresponding column.
Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work. I haven't got your text file to test but you should be able to work it out from it....

```
Sub ImportText()

Dim LineString As String
Dim sSourceFile As String
Dim r As Long
Dim fLen As Long
Dim fn As Integer
Dim CutterPA, CutterBR, CutterRad As Double

'Text file and path
sSourceFile = "C:\filtest.txt"

'sSourceFile doesn't exist
If Len(Dir(sSourceFile)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Gets a free file number from the operating system
fn = FreeFile

'Opens the file for input
Open sSourceFile For Input As #fn
fLen = LOF(fn)
r = 2
While Not EOF(fn)
   Line Input #fn, LineString

    If InStr(LineString, "(Cutter PA)") > 0 Then
        CutterPA = Val(Split(LineString, "=")(1))
    End If

    If InStr(LineString, "(Cutter BR)") > 0 Then
        CutterBR = Val(Split(LineString, "=")(1))
    End If

    If InStr(LineString, "(Cutter Radius)") > 0 Then
        CutterRad = Val(Split(LineString, "=")(1))
    End If

    'Write values if new item
    If InStr(LineString, "(***********") > 0 Then
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(r, 1).Value = CutterPA
            .Cells(r, 2).Value = CutterBR
            .Cells(r, 3).Value = CutterRad
        End With

        r = r + 1
    End If


Wend

'Closes the text file
Close #fn

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Can you share me your mail-id so that i can share   my text file with you. mean while i will try the code what you have send and very sorry for the late reply, i was on vacation,

Comment: Hi @Aeneas I tried to upload the text file here but its not working. i am getting few error when running the code. I run line by line and got error in the very first line of this if loop.                                                             If InStr(0, LineString, "(Cutter PA)") > 0 Then
        CutterPA = Val(Split(LineString, "=")(1))
 End If                                                                                                         The error what i am getting is " Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: I removed the optional parameter from the InStr function. Please try again